# При добавление блока в другой блок через appendChild пропадает фокус у inputa в добавленном блоке

Tags: javascript, css, input, focus

Есть блок `div`. При клике на этот блок в нем появляется блок с `input`'ом через `appendChild`. Когда кликаешь на этот `input` то сразу же пропадает фокус и невозможно ввести текст.

```js
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
var info = document.getElementById('info-block');

for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.appendChild(info);
    info.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.item p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#add_block {
  display: none;
}


/* Добавление блока  */

#info-block {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 160px;
  top: -22px;
  position: relative;
}

#info-block {
  background: #fff;
  /* border: 2px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.7); */
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#info-block:after,
#info-block:before {
  content: '';
  border: solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 0;
}

#info-block:before {
  border-right-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.7);
  border-width: 12px;
}

#info-block:after {
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 12px;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.new_event,
.date_new_event,
.people_new_event {
  width: 93%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.add_new_info,
.del_old_info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px;
}

.txt_write {
  width: 97%;
}

.item {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 141px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6!important;
  border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6!important;
  /* outline: 1px solid #dee2e6!important; */
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-block" style="display: none;">
  <div class="info-block-data">
    <input type="text" class="new_event" name="new_event" id="new_event" placeholder="Событие">
    <input type="text" class="date_new_event" name="date_new_event" id="date_new_event" placeholder="День, месяц, год">
    <input type="text" class="people_new_event" name="people_new_event" id="people_new_event" placeholder="Участники">
    <textarea name="txt_write" class="txt_write" id="" cols="22" rows="10" placeholder="Описание"></textarea>
    <button class="btn add_new_info" id="add_new_info">Готово</button>
    <button class="btn del_old_info" id="del_old_info">Удалить</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item bl">Понедельник, 25</div>
```

Comment: Добавляйте код, иллюстрирующий проблему, в вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Вы код забыли вставить

Comment: добавил код, суть такова - кликаю на блок с класс item и появляется его дочка инфо блок с input's и textarea и button

Answer (score 1):

Все из-за того, что клик срабатывает чаще, чем вы думаете, когда вы кликаете на всплывающую форму, вы так же кликаете на исходный элемент, после чего форма заново добавляется в конец документа, при этом удаляется из исходного местоположения, после вставки заново она уже без фокуса:

```js
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
var info = document.getElementById('info-block');

for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target)
    if(this !== e.target)
      return;
    
    this.appendChild(info);
    info.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
#info-block {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 160px;
  top: -22px;
  position: relative;
}

#info-block {
  background: #fff;
  /* border: 2px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.7); */
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="info-block" style="display: none;">
  <div class="info-block-data">
    <input type="text" class="new_event" name="new_event" id="new_event" placeholder="Событие">
    <input type="text" class="date_new_event" name="date_new_event" id="date_new_event" placeholder="День, месяц, год">
    <input type="text" class="people_new_event" name="people_new_event" id="people_new_event" placeholder="Участники">
    <textarea name="txt_write" class="txt_write" id="" cols="22" rows="10" placeholder="Описание"></textarea>
    <button class="btn add_new_info" id="add_new_info">Готово</button>
    <button class="btn del_old_info" id="del_old_info">Удалить</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item bl">Понедельник, 25</div>
```